# Tenda F3 isn't working correctly after firmware upgrade

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, firmware

I upgraded the firmware(the correct firmware from the website) and that seems to have messed the router up. Whatever I configured before is still there and works but the router login page(192.168.0.1) does not load. I get internet access through WiFi but 192.168.0.1 just says "The page isn’t redirecting properly". I don't want to reset the router because I'm scared I wont be able to configure it after that and cant use it. Anyway I can get to the firmware upgrade screen so I could re-flash the router firmware?

Comment: Try a different browser.

Comment: I did, I tried clearing cookies too; doesn't work

Comment: Right now I'm in the same situation. It is working, without the interface. Too many redirects is the error that Chrome shows.

Did you reset the router in the end to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to V11.13.01.23_EN from V11.13.01.06_EN and had the same issue. The web page of the router wouldn't open.
I disconnected the power and all the data (ethernet) cables. Connected the power cable and hold the WPS/Reset button for good two minutes. Router restart couple times, then I connected my laptop with the patch cord. This helped, I can login into the router again.
Hope this helps!